# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments error for below code snippet

Tags: java, junit

I am using class Collection and has a line of code as shown below. 
Please find the complete code as shown below and let me know what is wrong with this code as I am getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Parameterizing {
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String Password;
    int age;

    public void paratemeterizing(String Firstname, String Lastname, String Password, int age) {
        this.Firstname = Firstname;
        this.Lastname = Lastname;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getdata() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[2][4];
        data[0][0]= "David";
        data[0][1]= "Beck";
        data[0][2] = "1234";
        data[0][3] = 12;
        data[1][0]= "David";
        data[1][1]= "Bear";
        data[1][2] = "12345";
        data[1][3] = 21;
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void doLogin() {
        System.out.println(Firstname+Lastname+Password+age);
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments . Using Eclipse and JUint.

Comment: Which line of your code are you getting the error on?

Comment: Incorrect constructor name.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that the size of the data structure you return from `getdata()` doesn't match the parameters required by the method being tested.

I suspect that `Arrays.asList()` doesn't handle the types the way you expect.  It is declared using varargs, and so I can call `Arrays.asList(a)` and get a list containing one element, or I can call `Arrays.asList(a, b, c)` and get back a list containing three element.  The problem arises when the type of `a` is an array: did you want a list containing one array or did you want a list containing the elements of the array?  This ambiguity may be the problem (or at least one of them).  I would rewrite it like this:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata() {

    final List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

    result.add( new Object[] {"David", "Beck", "1234", 12} );
    result.add( new Object[] {"David", "Bear", "12345", 21} );

    return result;
}
```

*(I am not familiar with the JUnit annotations you are using, so that is why I made an educated guess)*

Comment: Appreciate the Replies and Answers. The class name and constructor name were different so I was getting the error. After correcting the constructor method name , the code is executing fine

Comment: This solved my exact problem - I was constructing the elements in the array ambiguously. Thanks for the tip!